# Conditionals using current time format

Tags: conditionals, date

does anyone know why this code will not display correctly?
It looks right to me.

```
{if "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "06.11" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "07.01"}
6 Jan

{if:elseif "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "06.01" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "21.02"}
20 Feb

{if:elseif "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "20.02" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "28.03"}
27 Mar

{if:elseif "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "27.03" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "16.05"}
15 May

{if:elseif "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "15.05" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "04.08"}
3 Aug

{if:elseif "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "03.08" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "12.09"}
11 Sept

{if:elseif "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" >= "11.09" && "{current_time format='%d.%m'}" <= "07.11"}
6 Nov
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing numbers. {current_time format='%d.%m'} is outputted as 18.08. This number is bigger than 06.01 and smaller than 21.02. Therefor it is correct that the text 20 Feb is printed.

Use epoch dates to compare. It is a reliable solution.

Edit: The plugin [Str To Time](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/str-to-time) seems to have what you want. Use it to convert the date you want to compare to, to a timestamp. Something like this:

```
{if {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && 
    {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="January 7th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
    6 Jan
{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="August 3th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && 
    {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="September 9th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
11 Sept
{if:else}
No date available
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi Balloonatic. Thanks for the answer. Not sure what you mean by "epoch dates" Can you please elaborate with an example.

Comment: Epoch is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. You will get it if you use {current_time format="%U"}. This can be a usefull website: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Is the date comparing you want, the same for each year?

Comment: Yes, same for each year. I just want to compare day and month.

Comment: I added a solution for your case.

Comment: Hi Balloonatic, That cracked it! Thanks so much for the assistance. Wonderful :)

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that this does in fact not work. {if {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && 
    {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="January 7th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
    6 Jan